# Salesforce - SOQL Query Syntax Error at Object UserRecordAccess

Tags: salesforce, soql

According to the Salesforce manual describing the access control using the object "UserRecordAccess" [[here]](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm), I'd like to obtain a list 
of permissions for a given "User" and "Case" in Salesforce.

Using the interactive workbench tool, I received the following syntax error at the construction of this query:

**SOQL Query:**

```
SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess FROM  UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId = 'abc123xyz..' AND RecordId in (SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE CaseNumber = '10001026')
```

**Validation Message at Workbench:**

```
MALFORMED_QUERY: The left operand field in the where expression for outer query should be an id field, cannot use: 'RecordId'
```

Is an alternate syntax available in SOQL to build such type of nested query?

**Solution found:** 
As a solution path, following the answer posted below, I've wrote a code in an APEX script with a REST interface, which executes the three SOQL queries in sequence. See the code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/sfcheckap/*')
// sample:  /services/apexrest/sfcheckap/00001028&myid@red.com  
//
global with sharing class MyRestResource1 {

    @HttpGet
    global static Boolean doGet() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        String myinput = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        List<String> inputList = myinput.split('&');
        String mycase = inputList[0];
        String myemail = inputList[1]; 
        sObject s1 = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Email = :myemail]; 
        ID MyUserId = s1.ID; 
        Case s2 = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE CaseNumber = :mycase LIMIT 1]; 
        ID MyCaseId = s2.ID; 
        System.debug('Dynamic MyCaseId is: ' + MyCaseId);
        UserRecordAccess s3 = [SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess FROM UserRecordAccess 
                               WHERE UserId = :MyUserId AND RecordId = :MyCaseId]; 
        ID MyRecordId = s3.ID;
        Boolean result = s3.HasReadAccess;   
        return result;        
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're SOQL Query in the WHERE clause will return a set of id's (`SET<ID>`) then the field being compared to one instance of the set should of the same datatype I believe.

Here is what the UserAccessRecord sObject looks like:

```
global class UserRecordAccess extends SObject 
{
    global Boolean HasAllAccess;
    global Boolean HasDeleteAccess;
    global Boolean HasEditAccess;
    global Boolean HasReadAccess;
    global Boolean HasTransferAccess;
    global String MaxAccessLevel;
    global String RecordId;
    global SObjectType SObjectType;
    global User User;
    global Id UserId;
    global APTTaskTemplate__c UserRecordAccess;

    global UserRecordAccess()
    {
    }
}
```

As you can see `UserAccessRecord.RecordId` is of type `String`.

You should be able to do this in 2 SOQL queries I believe, first SOQL Query would get the Case Ids and convert it to a List Type. Second would use that list.